# Set session variable from cookie is a good idea?

Tags: php, session, cookies

users from a PWA that my company have programmed are reporting some bad experiences on it. They got a blank page when they returned on the app after getting out of it. The PWA is accessible with a token includes in an url that we sent to our users.

The app is using PHP and JQuery Mobile (ouch).

After analyzing the program, it seems that the users are losing their session after a while (not sure about how many times exactly).

```
session_start();

if ( isset($_GET['token']) ) $_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['token']) ) exit('No tokens');

setcookie("token", $_SESSION['token'], time()+3600*24*30*5);

...
```

My solution is to set the variable 'token' in session with the cookie's token :

```
session_start();

if ( isset($_GET['token']) ) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];
} else if ( isset($_COOKIE['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_COOKIE['token'];
}

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['token']) ) exit('No tokens');

setcookie("token", $_SESSION['token'], time()+3600*24*30*5);

...
```

My solution is working but not sure if there are no better ways to solve this issue. Could you please assist me about it ?

Comment: The folks losing session, are they being inactive for a period of time?

Comment: Yes, but can't tell you how many time they have been inactive. Most of time, users have put the pwa in background, and when they come back, session is lost.